# How to construct rege for N.S. or N.A

Tags: regex

I want to construct a regex for `N.S` or `N.A`.

So far I am able to construct `(N\.A\b)|(N\.S\.\b)`. But it matches only `N.S` but not `N.S.`

Thanks

Comment: You have to escape `.`, because it is a special character for [tag:regex].

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. This should work in PHP if you are trying to match the entire word:

```
^(N\.A|N\.S)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript one:

```
const regex = /^N\.[SA]$/gm

regex.test('N.S') // true
regex.test('N.A') // true
regex.test('anything else') // false
```